# Drupal 6 How to hide fileds on creating content but show on editing content?

Tags: drupal-6, nodes

I have two fields, start date and end date. I want to hide end date while adding new content and want start date not editable on editing and show end date to edit. How I can do that in drupal 6 node module?

Answer (score 0):

use form alter and you can user url paramters to see if it is add or edit form
If Add Form say 
`$form['start_date']['#access']=false;`
and skip the same in edit form